# Limit of hypergeometric series and gamma function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

MMA does not calculate the limit, however the limit exists as seen in the approximative plot.

```
Limit[HypergeometricPFQ[{-1/2}, {1/2, m/2}, x]/Gamma[m], m -> 0]
```

How to achieve the limit?

[image]

MMA 13.0

Comment: Do you know of a transformation that would show the limit exists? Otherwise this looks like a math question, rather than a MMA one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/17/01/01/0003/) identity from the Wolfram functions website. This reads:

```
equation = HypergeometricPFQ[{a1}, {b, b2}, z] == 
((2 + 2 b - b2) HypergeometricPFQ[{a1}, {1 + b, b2}, z])/ b + ((-2 - b + b2)/b
 + z/( b (1 + b))) HypergeometricPFQ[{a1}, {2 + b, b2}, z] 
 + ((-2 + a1 - b) z HypergeometricPFQ[{a1}, {3 + b, b2}, z])/( b (1 + b) (2 + b));
```

To match your case, use the substitution rule (note that the function is symmetric in the two lower parameters):

```
substitute = {a1 -> -1/2, b -> m/2, b2 -> 1/2};
```

This means you want the limit of the following expression:

```
expression = (equation[[2]] /. substitute)/Gamma[m]
```

> [image]

Expand the `expression` around `m==0` to leading order, and truncate the result to the leading term:

```
limit = Series[expression, {m, 0, 0}] // Normal
```

> [image]

You can check that the plot is correct:

```
Plot[limit, {z, -2, 2}]
```

> [image]

Comment: @granularbastard Note that the whole purpose of using the identity is to unfold the `b` parameter into `b+1`, `b+2`, `b+3` to resolve the degenerate point `b->0`. This means you should be using the symmetry of the function under interchange of the two `b` parameters and do the substitution as: `a1->m-1/2; b2->1/2+m/2; b->m/2`. Then it should go through as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with a bit of manual work. Note that [HypergeometricPFQRegularized](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQRegularized.html) is close to what OP wants. So define

```
f=HypergeometricPFQ[{-1/2},{1/2,m/2},x];
g=HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{-1/2},{1/2,m/2},x];
```

Using `FunctionExpand[g]` it is easy to see that

```
FullSimplify[f/Gamma[m]==g*Sqrt[Pi]*(Gamma[m/2]/Gamma[m])]
(* True *)
```

Therefore the limit OP is looking for can be obtained as follows:

```
Limit[g*Sqrt[Pi],m->0]*Limit[Gamma[m/2]/Gamma[m],m->0]
(* -2*x*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2},{3/2,2},x] *)
```

Comment: The conversion can be obtained by `Solve[
 HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{a}, {b, c}, x] == (HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{a}, {b, c}, x] // FunctionExpand), HypergeometricPFQ[{a}, {b, c}, x]]`